# Is it possible to somehow dequeue actions from a CUDA stream?

Tags: cuda, scheduling

On a CUDA stream, we can enqueue:

- launches (kernels, callbacks)
- event operations (wait on, trigger)
- memory operations (copy, set, attach)

But there are no API calls for *dequeuing* any of these operations. Are there ways to achieving the same effect - for some or all of these kinds of operations?

Note: Not ruling out suggestions involving destroying the stream.

Answer (score 1):

For launches, we can write our kernels and/or callbacks to:

- Take the address of a (host or device side) "aborted" flag as a parameter
- Query that flag's value before doing anything else
- If the flag is up, do nothing and merely return.

in which case one can abort them by setting their flag on. A bit wasteful, but not terribly.

I'm not sure about everything else though.